# AngularJs unable to use custom directive inside tr

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've just started looking at AngularJs.  I was attempting to use a custom directive inside a tr element.  I get the following error regarding the switch directive

> Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchWhen', can't be  found!

Some sample code is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YiSFYK5l8mNIlBo6OGFW

Even after I removed the swtich it still doesn't seem to do anything. I changed the repeat direct to be over currentSheetData and removed the swtich entirly but there's no code in the rows.

However in my example I do the same setup inside a div element and it works fine.  Would someone explain what I'm doing incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

You need `ng-switch` directive on the parent node before declaring `ng-switch-when` on the child node.

Example:

```
<div class="animate-switch-container"
    ng-switch on="selection">
      <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="settings">Settings Div</div>
      <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="home">Home Span</div>
      <div class="animate-switch" ng-switch-default>default</div>
</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

Comment: Have you checked my example?  I'm pretty sure my example has that.

Comment: My bad. sorry about that